# Parse content of one column, and insert result to another one using flask and flask-migrate

Tags: flask, migration

I have to get content from one column in my DB, parse it, add new column and insert the result of the first step to this new one. After that "source column" should be dropped. The problem is that I have no idea how to perform such operation, and to persist migrations routine at the same time. I mean, if someone build a database, migrations should pass one by one, including this "weird" one.

My first thought  was to edit migration file, and execute some script between creating new column and dropping old one, so new column will be populated, before I drop old one.

```
def upgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.add_column('requests', sa.Column('payload', sa.Text(), nullable=True))
    move_requests_to_payload() # ???
    op.drop_column('requests', 'get_url')
    op.drop_column('requests', 'portal')
    # ### end Alembic commands ###
```

Something like this one above.
Do you guys have any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Allright, maybe someone will use this answer.

1. Firstly, I deleted field that should be dropped at the end from my model class and added new column, and generated migration file.
2. Because at this point model class did not know about this field I was forced to use raw SQL to fetch data from DB.

```
def upgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    conn = op.get_bind() 
    session = orm.Session(bind=conn) # it will be used later to update my db
    res = conn.execute('select id, get_url, collection_identifier from requests')
    results = res.fetchall() # this one fetch data from db
    get_urls = [{'id':r[0],'get':r[1]} for r in results] # this one parse response to list of dicitonaries
```

3. When I got this data, I created new column by `op.add_column()` method, and at this point I was able to use sqlalchemy ORM.
4. Last part of solution is quite obvious, because I just queried DB for objects, and updated them using data from 2.
5. After table is updated, I deleted old column.